# Textarea Limit words per line Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea field in my view.

I need to set per line only 1 word.

If the user tries to enter second word on the same line the word should be on the next one. (does not matter if he presses enter or space)

Also how can I restrict the user from typing comas.

The idea is only 1 word per line nothing more.

How to set these restrictions using jquery or javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: Please, provide code that you tried at this moment.

Comment: I have no code at the moment. I have no idea where to start... because It's a weird task.

Comment: Start with getting familiar with [keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change `event.target.value` on the `keyup` events on the textarea.

You can do something like, assuming your textarea has an ID of `#textArea`,

```
document.getElementById( 'textArea' ).onkeyup = function ( e ) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace( ' ', '\n' )
    .replace( ',', '' );
}
```

This would replace all your spaces to `\n`, which is a new line, and also take rid of all the commas.

I would go on to say `onkeyup` is not the most elegant method to do this. You should instead use `addEventListener( 'keyup', callback )`